# How to assign an event handler to a programmatically created picturebox

Tags: c#, event-handling, picturebox

How can I assign an event handler  to a programmatically created `PictureBox` in Windows Forms Application C#?
Edit:

I tried This, it's giving the error

> no Overload pictureBox_MouseDown

```
this.ListFrameImage[i].MouseDown += new EventHandler(this.pictureBox_MouseDown);

private void pictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    someX = e.X;
    someY = e.Y;
    drag = true;
}
```

Comment: Its good to add code examples of what you have tried, otherwise its just a write my code question and shows no work on your own to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an event handler using the += operator:

```
pictureBox.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(your_event_handler);
```

Or:

```
pictureBox.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler((o, a) => code here);
```

Hitting Tab after you write += will generate handler. Or you can write it 
manually :

```
pictureBox.MouseClick += pictureBox_MouseClick;

void pictureBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   // blah
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help can you take a look at my question one more time? I added some extra content

Comment: You need to use new MouseEventHandler